# C++ Return indexes of lowest values in array

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to return indexes of lowest values in an array, and i'm unable to find a good solution anywhere.

```
int indexofSmallestElement(double array[], int size)
{
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] < array[index])
            index = i;              
    }

    return index;
}
```

This is the probably the simplest way of finding index of one value, but what if I have multiple lowest values in an array?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: Return a vector of indexes?

Comment: "but what if I have multiple lowest values in an array?" – sounds to me, like if you're not interested in findling the minimum element, but rather finding valleys (i.e. inverse peaks) in a signal. This actually is a surprisingly rich field. See this overview of what NumPy supports: https://pythonawesome.com/overview-of-the-peaks-dectection-algorithms-available-in-python/

Comment: @datenwolf Maybe it's valleys, maybe it's duplicates of the minimum value. It's hard to tell.

Comment: Or multiple "valleys" of the same depth.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Oh, I just realized from the comment that there is the possibility of duplicate values, so if the question is actually that, you could do this, it also returning a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> indexesOfSmallestElements(double array[], int size)
{
    std::vector<int> indexes = { 0 };

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        double current_smallest = array[indexes.front()];

        if (array[i] < current_smallest) {
            indexes.clear();
            indexes.emplace_back(i);
        }
        else if (array[i] == current_smallest) {
            indexes.emplace_back(i);
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL**:

"Lowest" is always only one, if you want "lower than a value", just return a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> indexesOfSmallElements(double array[], int size, double value)
{
    std::vector<int> indexes;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < value) {
            indexes.emplace_back(i);
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array indices are a fairly inflexible concept, in C++ you can gain plenty of generality with iterators - there's a whole lot of C++ algorithms that take iterators directly, and essentially next to nothing in the standard library uses naked indices.

### C++20 & onwards

We can create a `minimums` range view (lazy range combinator) that takes a range, and returns a range that only contains the minimums from the original range. The range isn't a new vector with filtered elements: it is a view onto the original range (e.g. onto the original vector of doubles).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template <typename Range>
auto minimums(Range && range) {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    auto first_min = min_element(range);
    auto const is_min = [=](auto const &el){ return el == *first_min; };
    return subrange(first_min, std::end(range)) | views::filter(is_min);
}
```

You definitely do not need to recover the indices of the array - iterators are a generic concept and apply quite widely. But just to show a solution equivalent to the one for C++17 & prior below, let's write some adapters that'll help with index recovery:

```
template <typename Range>
auto addressof(Range && range) {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    return views::transform(range, [](auto &el){ return &el; });
}

template <typename Range, typename It>
auto array_indices(Range && range, It && reference) {
    using namespace std::ranges;
    auto to_index = [ref_addr = &*reference](auto *el){ return ref_addr - el; };
    return range | addressof | views::transform(to_index);
}
```

And now we can test it:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const double array[] = {8, 3, -1, -1, 9, -1, 5};
    auto min_range = minimums(array);

    {   // test
        auto min = std::ranges::min_element(array);
        // have we got the correct number of minimums?
        auto min_size = std::distance(std::begin(min_range), std::end(min_range));
        assert(min_size == std::count(std::begin(array), std::end(array), *min));
        // are all of the minimums indeed minimums?
        assert(std::ranges::all_of(min_range,
            [=](auto &el){ return el == *min; }));
        // are all of the minimums references to the array
        assert(std::ranges::all_of(min_range,
            [&](auto &el){ return &el >= std::begin(array) && &el < std::end(array); }));
    }

    for (auto &min : min_range)
        std::cout << std::distance(std::begin(array), &min) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 5
```

### C++17 through C++11

Thus, let's have a `minimumLocations` function that takes two forward iterators that define a range, and return a vector of iterators to all the minimums that were found:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename I1, typename I2>
std::vector<I1> minimumLocations(I1 start, I2 end)
{
  if (start == end) return {};
  std::vector<I1> locations = {start};
  std::decay<decltype(*start)>::type min = *start;
  std::advance(start, 1);

  for (; start != end; std::advance(start, 1)) {
    auto const &value = *start;
    if (value < min) {
      // new minimum
      locations.clear();
      locations.push_back(start);
      min = *start;
    }
    else if (value == min)
      locations.push_back(start);
  }

  return locations;
}
```

For convenience's sake, we can also have an adapter function that takes a range instead of a pair of iterators. In C++, a "range" is anything that has a beginning and an end:

```
template <typename R>
auto minimumLocations(R &range) {
    return minimumLocations(std::begin(range), std::end(range));
}
```

Both of the functions will work on any container that provides forward iterators - not only on arrays, but also vectors, lists, forward lists, etc. A specialized version could also be provided for pre-sorted containers.

And now a test and a demo:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const double array[] = {8, 3, -1, -1, 9, -1, 5};
    auto min_indices = minimumLocations(array);

    {   // test
        auto min = std::min_element(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
        // have we got the correct numer of locations?
        assert(min_indices.size() == std::count(std::begin(array), std::end(array), *min));
        // are all of the locations indeed minimums?
        assert(std::all_of(std::begin(min_indices), std::end(min_indices), 
               [=](auto it){ return *it == *min; }));
    }

    for (auto i : min_indices)
      std::cout << std::distance(array, i) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 5
```